# column / list operators for datetime values in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the columns consists of datetime values with varying frequences.

I want to create a new column which flags whenever the gap between two datetime values is greater than one day (datetime current row + timedelta(days=1) < datetime next row).

However, I would want to do this with a list operation, rather than a for loop.

Had the values been int values, you could do something like:

```
df_ship["gap_gt_1"] = (df_ship['datetime']+1).lt(df_ship['datetime'].shift().bfill()).astype(int)
```

However, lt and similar operators don't work with datetime objects.

I've tried to do the following, but it only returns 'false' values.

```
df_ship["gap_gt_1"] = ((df_ship['datetime'] + timedelta(days=1)) < (df_ship['datetime'].shift()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do:

```
import numpy as np

# Take the difference in dates
df["timedelta"] = df['date'] - df['date'].shift(1)

# To make the flags
conditions, type_choices = ([df['timedelta'] > pd.Timedelta(days=1)], [1])
df["flag"] = np.select(conditions, type_choices, default=0)
```